# On window load or resize - set element property JS. Can't find error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to set the width of a column element dynamically using js / jquery on wordpress. I'm taking this approach because my theme is hijacking my css and I have experienced an unprecedented amount of stubbornness from it.

Here is my code, I know 100% that jquery is loading and that javascript executes (by putting in alerts and testing etc.), all help appreciated!

My html is along the lines of

```
<div class="3-col-force">test</div>
<div class="3-col-force">test</div>
<div class="3-col-force">test</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = fixCol();
window.onresize = fixCol();
function fixCol(){  
    var offset = getWidth();
    if (offset > 765) {
        setColumnWidth('33%');
    } else {
        setColumnWidth('100%'); 
    }
}
function setColumnWidth(newWidth){
    var columns = document.querySelector(".3-col-force");
        columns.style.width = newWidth;
}
function getWidth() {
  var width = $(window).width(); 
  return width;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use JQuery I would suggest the code below. I believe it is what your are attempting to accomplish with your code.

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/bazma5st/29/

Javascript/Jquery:

```
//set the limit
var limit = 765;

//the column class
var colClass = $(".3-col-force");

//window resize event
$(window).on("resize",function(){//begin on resize event

  //if the window is greater than the limit
  if ($(this).width() > limit) {//begin if then else

      //set its width to 33%
      colClass.width("33%");

    } else {

        //set its width to 33%
        colClass.width("100%");

    }//end if then else

//end of window on resize event
}).on("load",function(){//begin on load event for window load

    //if the window is greater than the limit
  if ($(this).width() > limit) {//begin if then else

      //set its width to 33%
      colClass.width("33%");

    } else {

        //set its width to 33%
        colClass.width("100%");

    }//end if then else


});//end on window load event
```